# CSS selectors: multiple classes descended from an ancestor

Tags: css, css-selectors

Is there a better way than this to select the elements with classes options OR inputs that are descendants of #height without selecting any elements with those classes that are not descendants of #height?

```
#height .inputs, #height .options
```

The #height seems redundant but #height .inputs,.options selects all the class="options" on the page, not just those descended from #height.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope, that's just how CSS is designed, and it's one of the reasons I use [LESS CSS](http://lesscss.org/) on all of my projects now. With LESS, you can structure your CSS more like JavaScript by nesting selectors. For example:

```
#height {
    .inputs, .options {
        /* properties */
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**metadept** is absolutely correct. The comma is separating your selectors, and since you aren't specifying that you want the `.options` that are children of `#height`, it will target every element with the class `.options` on the page.

[LESS CSS](http://www.lesscss.org) is a great tool to use; you may also want consider [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/) - it just boils down to what you're more comfortable with.

Comment: The main reason I recommend LESS over SASS (aside from my familiarity with LESS) is that the client-side compilation makes development a lot easier. In production environments they're both well-supported and it probably depends on which is better supported by other third-party frameworks and plugins you're using.

Comment: Yup. Personally, I prefer using LESS as well - I just felt the need to let him know about SASS too :)

Comment: Thanks guys. I've looked at LESS, just haven't started down that road yet. I am quite new to css and web development in general, so I want to make sure I start with a solid understanding of the underpinnings before moving on to libraries and other higher-level tools: CSS before LESS, JavaScript before JQuery, etc. Thanks again.

Comment: @burgerB I agree with that except for the JavaScript before jQuery part. Personally I found it a lot easier to learn by starting out with jQuery since the base JavaScript element selection and manipulation is so obtuse.